# How to access a service from spring boot jar to spring mvc application. Individually when i execute spring boot jar it works fine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Error: No qualifying bean of type 'Service' available.expected Atleast 1 qualifying bean which qualifies as Autowire candidate.Dependency annotations

Added ComponentScan :

@ComponentScan({.........}) to a config in spring-mvc project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.